# vim plugin with python gtk, works in gvim but hangs in terminal

Tags: vim, pygtk, vim-plugin

I wrote this colorpicker vim plugin hosted in [this repo](https://github.com/abijr/colorpicker). It works as in intended in gvim (open dialog with  and input the color). But when I run vim in a terminal, the gtk window hangs after clicking the ok or cancel buttons (although it inserts the selected color)... no error messages in vim.

Do any of you have encountered this problem? have you been able to solve it?

Comment: So, what's your particular question? Or do your expect us to investigate and fix the problem for you?!

Comment: There is no problem with the code itself, it works correctly under gvim. I expected some insight into the workings of terminal vim and python vs. gvim and python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid to open any GUI dialog from vim.

But... try `gtk.quit()` after destroying dialog because `color_dlg.destroy()` do not to terminate gtk thread.

Comment: by "avoid opening a GUI dialog from vim", do you mean, "avoid opening a GUI dialog from terminal vim"?
I never created a gtk "main" or "main loop" there is no "gtk.quit()"

Comment: "avoid opening a GUI dialog from terminal vim". Exactly!
"I never created a gtk "main" or "main loop" there is no "gtk.quit()" you are right.